# Invalid class name select by jQuery

Tags: jquery

There's a system written by my colleague.
And I'm confused by the jQuery's work.

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <div class="1_01_001">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log($('#test.1_01_001').text()); // get empty string
  console.log($('#test .1_01_001').text()); // get textContent of that element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#test.1_01_001` selector is looking for elements with an ID of "test", who also has a class of "1_01_001"

The `#test .1_01_001` selector is looking for an element with a class of "1_01_001", who is also a descendant of an element with the ID of "test"

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question is really about the format of a CSS selector. Without the space between the id and the class, it's trying to find an element that has both the id of `test` and the class of `1_01_001` on the same element. @kid, you have `test` id on the first div and the `1_01_001` class on the div inside it. So, they're not on the same element.  I created a [demo](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/JGyYNP) at CodePen that makes this a little easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

The second alternative is working because is properly using the Descendant Selector of jQuery, you have to use a whitespace. Read more here http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/